# I was waiting "in" vs "inside" the tent for amazing view (outside)

Tags: grammar

So there is two things I am not sure.

1) Do I have to be detail to describe the amazing view is outside of the tent to put "outside" at the end?

2) If I put "outside" then I should use "inside the tent" instead of "in the tent"?

I was reading about "in" vs "inside" usage...

http://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst2375_difference-between-inside-and-in.aspx

So yes, I am inside the tent, and we have to wait for the the the sunset or whatever (amazing view) outside of the tent.

For example, I am waiting inside the tent for the amazing sunset outside of the tent?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you tried giving a sample sentence. It seems like you're trying to say something like, "I'm inside the tent, but there's an amazing view outside the tent," but, without something concrete to look at, it's hard for me to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, let's say there is a sunset or aurora outside of the tent which will have to wait for it?

Comment: That user on the forum is spouting nonsense about _in_ not standing alone. Which parts of it were you concerned about? Also, there's no need to write `EDIT` when you edit your post, users who wish to see the differences can check the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to tents, I see no meaningful difference between *in the tent* and *inside the tent*. You can use either one. You can't be ***in*** the tent without being ***inside*** the tent.

Also, once you specify that you are in(side) the tent, you can simply use *outside*, and context will clarify.

> I am waiting inside the tent for the amazing sunset outside.

The same goes the other way around:

> In about 10 minutes, there should be an amazing sunset outside the tent, but I'm waiting inside for now.

or:

> In about 10 minutes, there should be an amazing sunset outside, but I'm waiting inside the tent for now.

Mentioning the tent by name only has to be done once, assuming a simply context where there's just one tent and we are either ***in*** it, or ***outside of*** it.

---

This thing about *in* being the same as *inside* is tricky, though. It works great for tents, but it doesn't work so well for idioms:

> **I am in the groove** ≠ I am inside the groove
>   **She is in the know** ≠ She is inside the know
>   **We are in a hurry** ≠ We are inside a hurry

Also, think about this one. If I say:

> I am inside the doghouse.

that means I've crawled inside the doghouse for some reason. However, if I say,

> I am [in the doghouse](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+doghouse).

that usually means my wife is mad at me (probably for spending too much time on ELL).